# Using rug in Rust with wasm-bindgen

Tags: javascript, rust, mpfr, wasm-bindgen

I'd like to use the rug crate with wasm-bindgen to allow me to use arbitrary-precision arithmetic in a web browser. Whenever I try to compile, though, it fails to build the library, saying something along the lines of

unresolved imports `libc::c_char`, `libc::c_int`, `libc::c_long`.

Is there a workaround for this? If Emscripten is involved that's fine, but I'd like to be able to mostly write Rust code.

Answer (score 1):

`rug` depends on `libc`

I found https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/issues/858#issuecomment-573331279

> By definition, `wasm32-unknown-unknown` has no `libc`. If you want to use emscripten or wasi you can use `wasm32-unknown-emscripten` or `wasm32-wasi`, both of which are already supported in the libc crate.

https://users.rust-lang.org/t/wasm-unknown-vs-emscripten/22997/5 looks like a good explanation about the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ibig](https://crates.io/crates/ibig). It has pure Rust code so it will compile to wasm no problem.

See also a performance comparison of different Rust libraries
[here](https://crates.io/crates/bigint-benchmark). ibig is quickly catching up to GMP's (and so rug's) performance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fork of GMP that claims to be compilable to WASM, presumably `wasm32-wasi`

- https://github.com/torquem-ch/gmp-wasm

Rug is mostly a Rust wrapper around GMP, but it should be possible to call WASM directly